# Back from Listwiew to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, expandablelistview, onbackpressed

I open the ExpandableListView from the Fragment, which is open from MainActivity.

In ListView, a listener is hung at the click of a button in Item.

By clicking this button I want to transfer some value to MainActivity and send it to WebView.

The fragment is opened with beginTransaction () and written to addToBackStack (null)

Everything works fine when I press the back button of the system button, but I just can’t figure out how in my ExpandableAdapter class, with which I open ExpandableListView to call OnBackPress for this Fragment ....

Now I just call MainActivity in onClick and pass the value through putExtra. But this every time reboots my Main Activity, but I do not need it, because it already exists, I just need to return to it.

**Call Fragment from MainActivity:**

```
    Fragment fragmentWeb = new MainFragment();
    FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();

    ft.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainlayout, fragmentWeb, dataFrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Part of MainFragment:**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressed {
        ......

        getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list).setVisibility(ViewGroup.VISIBLE);
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        new DownloadJason().execute();

        private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
             // Get Json...
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            listAdapter = new myExpandableListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listHeader, listDataChild, listDataHeader, getActivity());

            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

**part of myExpandableListAdapter:**

```
public class myExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Activity _activity;
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    private List<Integer> imgHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listData;
    private Integer imgType1,imgType2,imgType3,imgType4,imgType5;
    private FragmentManager manager;

    public myExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> listData,
                                   Activity activity) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this._listData = listData;
        this._activity = activity;

    }

    ......

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        final String markerId = (String) getData(groupPosition, 0);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        ImageButton btnMarker = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        btnMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_place_black);


        btnMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(_activity, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("markerId", markerId);
                _activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

.....

}
```

Comment: Use finish() which is a builtin function which will allow you to move to the latest previous activity in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two interface.

1.**MainFragmentListener** for communication with activity/fragment

2.**AdapterClickListener** for communication with adapter/fragment.

You must be initialize to **MainFragmentListener** like this.

```
MainActivity implements MainFragmentListener{
..
}
```

Create AdapterClickListener at MainFragment. 
like this.

```
MainFragmentListener mainFragmentListener = null;
```

then give **MainFragmentListener** to fragment.

```
Fragment fragmentWeb = new MainFragment();
fragmentWeb.adapterClickListener = this;
```

Create AdapterClickListener at MainFragment and **init at onCreatedView()**
then give this interface to adapter.

main fragment

```
 AdapterClickListener AdapterClickListener = null;
```

adapter constructor

```
public myExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> listData,
                                   Activity activity,AdapterClickListener adapterClickListener) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this._listData = listData;
        this._activity = activity;
        this.adapterClickListener = adapterClickListener;
    }
```

now you send what you want data to main activity with interface.

```
btnMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapterClickListener.markerClicked(*****);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much @denizs !!!

His tip prompted me in the right direction. But not everything suited me, for example, I did not understand why:

```
Fragment fragmentWeb = new MainFragment();
fragmentWeb.adapterClickListener = this;
```

But in general, what he wrote is true and solved my problem.
I consider his answer detailed and mark it as accepted.

---

And here I post my **final version:**.

Create interface:
**OnMarkerListener**

```
public interface OnMarkerListener{
    public void onMarkerRead(String marker);
}
```

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, OnMarkerListener {



    @Override
    public void onMarkerRead(String marker) {
        onBackPressed();
        inject(WebView, "openMarker(" + marker + ");", null);
    }

}
```

**MainFragment:**

```
    public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnBackPressed {

        OnMarkerListener markerListener;
        myExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
        ....

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context){
            super.onAttach(context);
            Activity activity = (Activity) context;
            try {
                markerListener = (OnMarkerListener) activity;
            }catch (ClassCastException e){
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ " must override onMarkerListener..");
            }
        }


       private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

         ......

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pDialog.dismiss();

                //call constructor
                listAdapter = new myExpandableListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                     listHeader, listDataChild, listDataHeader, getActivity(), 
                     markerListener);

                // setting list adapter
                expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

       }

    }
```

**And myExpanableListAdapter:**

```
private OnMarkerListener _markerListener;

public myExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                               HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,
                               HashMap<String, List<String>> listData,
                               Activity activity, OnMarkerListener markerListener){
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this._listData = listData;
    this._activity = activity;
    this._markerListener = markerListener;

}

.....

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    final String markerId = (String) getData(groupPosition, 0);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
    }

    ImageButton btnMarker = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    btnMarker.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_place_black);


    btnMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            _markerListener.onMarkerRead(markerId);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks. nice this code more better. your markerListener initialize method maybe wrong because sometimes activity null return  markerListener = (OnMarkerListener) activity. You can initialize to markerListener  when fragment create  

Fragment fragmentWeb = new MainFragment();
fragmentWeb.markerListener = this;